# "Reveal in Finder" functionality for Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer

How to preselect a file or directory in the Windows Explorer? What command line switches do I need? How to find out what command line switches the Explorer supports (`explorer /?` does not show something)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

explorer /path/to/dir opens an explorer window in that directory, or if it's a file, opens it with the default application.
There are [some explorer commandline options](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152457).

**edit:**

```
explorer /select,/path/to/something
```

will open explorer window in */path/to* with *something* selected

Comment: *Reveal in Finder* opens the containing directory and selects the file, if it's not a directory.

Comment: which is why I'm showing the link to the commandline options. Edited answer for clarity..

Comment: It would appear that Explorer gets "smart" on you and uses one window for a batch process with files in a similar directory.  Is there any way to force a new window for each file regardless of parent directory?

Comment: @humble_coder I'm afraid I don't understand your question, can you elaborate or provide an exaple of the functionality you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @stijn Basically, when using "explorer /select,/path/to/something" from the command line, Explorer will show it as selected (which is appropriate).  However, if I'm processing a list of files and some of those files happen to share a folder, it won't open a new window for that file, it simply re-presents that folder.  My goal is to open a new window for every file processed regardless of shared proximity to anything else -- 1-to-1 file to window.

Comment: @humble_coder this should do it: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/130510: "/n:  Opens a new window in single-paned (My Computer) view for each item
     selected, even if the new window duplicates a window that is
     already open."

Answer (score 1):

If your referring to the Mac popup shortcut "Reveal in Finder", this can be done with any **shortcut** on your PC.

It's as simple as right-clicking the shortcut and clicking "Open File Location". When you click this, it opens the location of the actual file and highlights it for you.

Also, depending on what internet browser you use, this functionality is also present when you download a file. For example, in Firefox, when you download a file, you can right-click the file in the "Downloads" window and select "Open containing folder". This performs the same as the "Open File Location" as aforementioned.

-Brandon